# Can't get user from Directoryentry

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I am getting crazy here, I'd really appreciate some help!
simply I want to get user name or anything from Active Directory using DirectoryEntry class.

I used userprinciple and it works great, but the property I need to get (user's manager) is only avaliable in DirectoryEntry.

My problem is, I looked so much online and I got the codes from there, but for some reason it never works, always return Null. here is an example :

```
public static DirectoryEntry GetUser(string UserName)
{
    //create an instance of the DirectoryEntry
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + "OU=AnotherOU,OU=xx,OU=Testvironments,DC=abc,DC=local");

    //create instance fo the direcory searcher
    DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

    deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
    //set the search filter
    deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(cn=" + UserName + "))";
    //deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

    //find the first instance
    SearchResult results = deSearch.FindOne();

    //if found then return, otherwise return Null
    if (results != null)
    {
        //de= new DirectoryEntry(results.Path,ADAdminUser,ADAdminPassword,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        //if so then return the DirectoryEntry object
        return results.GetDirectoryEntry();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have no clue why this code returns null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
//create instance for directory entry
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + "OU=AnotherOU,OU=xx,OU=Testvironments,DC=abc,DC=local");

//create instance fo the directory searcher
DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de );;

//set the search filter
deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(SAMAccountName=" + UserName+ ")(givenName=" + UserName+ ")(name=" + UserName+ ")(SN=" + UserName+ "))";

//find the first instance
SearchResult results = deSearch.FindOne();

//if found then return, otherwise return Null
if (results != null)
{
    //The desired property you want , you can extract in this way.
   DomainName = results .Properties["SamAccountName"][0].ToString();
   return domainName
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Domain name here is User ID from which user trying to log in to the machine.It is a unique ID.I am sorry, should have used some thing else here...

Comment: Filter string is missing closing parentheses at end.  I utilized string token of $"(&(objectClass=user)(|(SAMAccountName={UserName})(givenName={UserName})(name={UserName})(SN={UserName})))"  and the search worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the `cn`, `samAccountname`, `displayName` or `userPrincipalName` attributes? `samAccountName` is the traditional (NT 4.0) style user name, `displayName` is usually first name plus last name and the `userPrincipalName` is in a similar format to an E-mail address (user@domain.name).

Either way, if you want to test out different queries, use an interactive LDAP query tool like [ldp.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224543). It will probably be much easier than trying them out in code.